# AS3 - Error 1119 - Does not detect my static class altogether

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, static-members

Context: I began learning AS3 a week ago. All my files are in the same folder, and the path is set to `.` (by default anyway), so all classes should logically detect each other. But as it turns out, I have a class with a lot of `public static var`, and every time I call these in my other class, I get Error 1119

```
Access of possibly undefined property isKeyJump through a reference with static type Function.
```

The class with static variables is called `Cont` for 'Control'; it's basically meant to check which keys are pressed, *just* pressed, or pressed twice rapidly. I made the class to organize the code, essentially.

I declare all my variables like this:

```
public static var isKeyRight:Boolean = false;
```

And if that wasn't sufficiently explicit, I even wrote this in the constructor (I was tired):

```
public function Cont()
    {
        Cont.isKeyRight = false;
        ... }
```

But that didn't solve the issue at all. It appears the problem is independent from the class itself; it's *just* that my other class does not detect `Cont`.

I tried `import Cont;` but that also didn't change a thing. My 44 lines of Error 1119 look like this:

```
if (standing && Cont.isKeyJump) vacc = _jumpAcc;
```

I even made sure to instantiate the instance of `Cont` before that of my other class, to make sure that the definitions were at least there. But that would probably make an error after compilation if that was the issue, not during.

The bulk:

Other Class: (The one with 44 errors)

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class PersonnagePrincipal extends Physical {

    //INITIALISATION
    ...

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public function PersonnagePrincipal(life:Number = 100, focus:Number = 100, lifeMax:Number = 100, focusMax:Number = 100)
    {
        super();
        ...
    }

    // GET & SET
    public function set life(life:Number):void {    _life = (life > lifeMax) ? lifeMax : life;  }
    ...


    // UPDATE
    override public function update(event:Event)
    {
        move_physical();

        if (standing && Cont.isKeyJump) vacc = _jumpAcc;
        ...
```

And Cont:

```
package {

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.*;

public class Cont extends MovieClip
{
    // Key codes
    public static var isKeyRight:Boolean;
    public static var isKeyJump:Boolean;
    ...

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public function Cont()
    {
        Cont.isKeyRight = false;
        Cont.isKeyJump = false;
        ...

        if (stage) { init(); } 
        else { this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init); }
    }

    //POST-CONSTRUCTOR
    private function init(e:Event=null)
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        ...
    }
```

EDIT: Well, taking all the code from `Cont` and into `PersonnagePrincipal` does solve the synthax errors (given that I get rid of the `Cont.`) ... But now my code is a lot less sexy and flexible.

EDIT 2: I made the class `PersonnagePrincipal` empty, and it worked. Stranger still, when I put the line `public var control:Cont = new Control` in `Main`, it works, while it generates a compile time error in `PersonnagePrincipal`. What?

Comment: Did you declare a function named Cont in PersonnagePrincipal?

Comment: No, the only thing called Cont is the class.

Comment: Ya I can see that, "through a reference with static type Function" made me think you might have also accidentally declared it as a function